# Error updating notification hub Azure WNS

Tags: windows, azure, push-notification

Error updating notification hub:

> {"error":{"message":"SubCode=40000. Failed to validate credentials
>   with WNS. The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad
>   Request...TrackingId:aa79d90b-f09c-4549-8a06-2086f29f02f5_M11CH3_M11CH3_G12,TimeStamp:6/4/2019
>   12:15:26 PM","code":"BadRequest"}}

The above error occurs when saving Package SID and Security Key in Windows(WNS) in azure notification hub portal. Can you please help this issue

Comment: It's a Azure Notification Hubs configuration settings issue. Please follow the [Send notifications to Universal Windows Platform apps by using Azure Notification Hubs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-wns-push-notification) document to confirm all configurations are correct.

Comment: Thanks for your replay. I have followed that document and all the steps. After creating a secret key I have entered package SID and Secret key when saving that WNS key same issue occurs. Any idea?

Comment: You said that you create a secret key. Have you activated it?

Comment: How to activate the secret key? I have a check that pages but no option available?

Comment: In the application secrets section, when you click 'Generate a new Password', a new line is there, the 'Activate' button is on the same line.

Comment: @Xavier Xie Thanks for the reply. I have checked https://apps.dev.microsoft.com but there no option for "Active".  https://imgur.com/a/YPyYpuZ and https://imgur.com/a/UeP11hn

Comment: I hope you received the answer in this thread https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2e0f6af5-655e-49f3-8d8e-f647445346d2/notification-hub-failed-to-validate-credentials-with-wns?forum=notificationhubs

Comment: I have found the solution, Application Id updated in Package SID textbox then problem solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Package ID box we need to update Application ID and in Secret Key box, we need to update that new key generated in Application Secrets key.